# Using sprintf with multiple variables of different length in R

Tags: r, printf

I am working with R trying to use the sprintf function to print multiple urls. The URL is in the form http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/year/day.txt. I want to print the url for each day of multiple years. I tried:

`day <-c(1:365)
year <-c(2001:2004)
urls<- sprintf("http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/%s/%s.txt", year, day)`

but received the error

`Error in sprintf("http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/%s/%s.txt", year, day) : 
  arguments cannot be recycled to the same length`

I am printing these urls so I can import raw data from them in bulk.
 If anyone has any idea how to make this work with sprintf or another function please let me know

Answer (score 1):

What you want is `expand.grid` to generate the combinations of years and days.

```
times <- expand.grid(days=1:365, years=2001:2004)
urls <- sprintf("http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/%s/%s.txt", times$year, times$days)
head(urls)
[1] "http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/2001/1.txt"
[2] "http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/2001/2.txt"
[3] "http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/2001/3.txt"
[4] "http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/2001/4.txt"
[5] "http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/2001/5.txt"
[6] "http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/2001/6.txt"
```

That said, this will encounter problems with leap years, etc; you might want to consider `seq.Date` instead, like

```
dates <- as.POSIXlt(seq.Date(as.Date("2010-01-01"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), by="day"))
```

And then

```
urls <- sprintf(".../%s/%s", dates$year + 1900, dates$yday)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop:

```
days <- c(1:365)
years <- c(2001:2004)
urls <- c()

for (year in years) {
  for (day in days) {
    urls <- c(urls, sprintf("http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/%s/%s.txt", year, day))
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

your running into a wall because it can't recycle the values you gave it. (365/4 is not a whole number).

Just make one string out of the two and then use `sprintf`

```
day  <- c(1:365)
year <- c(2001:2004)
day.year <- paste(rep(year,each = 365),day,sep = '/')
sprintf('http://www.weather.unh.edu/data/%s.txt',day.year)
```

Cheers.